# Contraction Mapping maps boundary on boundary?

Tags: metric-spaces, contraction-operator

I remenber here the concept of a contraction mapping.

Definition:  Let (X, d) be a metric space. Then a map T : X → X is called a contraction mapping on X if there exists q ∈ [0, 1) such that

$$ d(T(x),T(y))\le qd(x,y) d(T(x),T(y))\le q d(x,y) \ \  x, y  \in X.$$

Assume that, $f :B \longrightarrow B$ is a contraction mapping and $B$ is a closed ball. I'd like to know if always
$$
f(\partial B)=\partial (f(B)) ?
$$

Comment: Take $f\equiv 0$. Then, $f$ is a contraction in whatever space you would like, but your claim will fail. It will also fail for $q<1$ in general, so this seems to be never possible...?

Comment: Thank you Alex, but I have modified my ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. As a counterexample consider $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = (|x_1|, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ on the unit ball. Then $f(\partial B) = \{x \in S^{n-1} : x_1 \ge 0\}$ and $\partial f(B) = f(\partial B) \cup \{x \in B: x_1 = 0\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. However, I'm afraid that your function isn't a comtraction mapping. In fact, if $x_1 \ge 0$ we have $f(x)=f(x)$ then it can not satisfies the inequality above for some $ q \in [0,1)$. Note that q is strictly smaller than 1. Could you think a litleo bit more about the problem?

Comment: You want a strict contraction? Take $f_1(x) = \frac{1}{2} f(x)$, where $f$ is defined as before. BTW this did not require too much thinking on my part and it should not have required much thinking on your part either.

Comment: Thank you, you're write I'll give you your score. But I'm goingo to put another question with another hyphothesis. Your counterexample isn't bijectve. Would you mind of thinking about this problem? That is, if the contraction mapping is bijective.

Comment: I put the question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862451/contractions-mappings-bijective-maps-boundarys-on-boundarys