# Contractions mappings bijective maps boundarys on boundarys?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, contraction-operator

I remenber here the concept of a contraction mapping.

Definition:  Let (X, d) be a metric space. Then a map T : X → X is called a contraction mapping on X if there exists q ∈ [0, 1) such that

$$ d(T(x),T(y))\le qd(x,y) d(T(x),T(y))\le q d(x,y) \ \  x, y  \in X.$$

Assume that, $f :B \longrightarrow f(B) \subset B$ is a bijective contraction mapping and $B$ is a closed ball. I'd like to know if always
$$
f(\partial B)=\partial (f(B)) ?
$$

I have a feeling that this statement is true.

Comment: A contraction mapping decreases the diameter of a metric space. There is no such thing as a bijective contraction mapping from the closed ball to itself (or of any metric space of finite diameter to itself). Presumably you mean an injective contraction mapping?

Comment: Ok, thank you I will modify my question.

Comment: Yes, an injective one.

Comment: What do you mean by $\partial B$? For instance, if $\partial B=\overline{B}\setminus\operatorname{int} B$ then the answer is negative (I assume that the middle term in the inequality is a misprint). Indeed, let $(X,d)$ be a segment $B=[0,1]$ endowed with the standard metric, and $T(x)=x/2$ for each $x\in X$. Then $\partial B=\varnothing$ whereas $\partial T(B)=\{1/2\}$.

Comment: Sorry,but $\partial B = \{ 0,1\} $, thus $ T(\partial B) = T( \{ 0,1\}))=\{0,1/2\} $ and $ \partial( T(B))=\{0,1/2\} $. Isnt't it?

Comment: No, $\partial B=\{0,1\}$ when $B$ is considered as a subspace of real line $X$. But when $B=X$ then $\partial B=\varnothing$ because each metric space $X$ is both closed and open in itself.